# Error /var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Tengo el siguiente codigo para levantar el docker y me encontre con varios problemas soy nuevo en docker y no sabria porque me sigue tirando el error probe dandole permisos 777 a la carpeta y por lo que estuve viendo puede ser dentro de la creacion del docker file si alguien me sabe responder.

```
 FROM php:7.4-fpm
    ARG user
    ARG uid
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        git \
        curl \
        libpng-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        zip \
        unzip
    RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd
    COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
    RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
    RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
        chown -R $user:$user /home/$user
    WORKDIR /var/www
    USER $user
```

Comment: Básicamente, el usuario del servidor, debe tener permiso de escritura en el directorio `storage/` del proyecto. Podrías probar con `RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R`, pero realmente no sé dónde está tu proyecto ahí. Además probablemente necesites una base de datos, por lo que esa imagen te va a quedar chica. ¿Por qué no usas [sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail), que ya viene con laravel?

Comment: no logro encontrar el storage cual seria la mejor  forma para encontrarlo?

Comment: ¿Debemos asumir que `/var/www` es un volumen que se exporta a un directorio del anfitrión? ¿Es una copia con `COPY` de datos locales? ¿Podrías indicarnos cómo despliegas este contenedor? Depende de cómo trates el contenido de `/var/www` o sus subdirectorios la solución está en el `Dockerfile` o en la máquina anfitriona.

Answer (score 1):

El usuario del servidor $user no tiene permisos de lectura, escritura; resultando en la denegación de permisos.

Por lo tanto, para resolver el asunto agrega la siguiente línea de código justo después de la declaración de tu espacio de trabajo **WORKDIR /var/www** .

```
RUN chown -R $user:$user /var/www
```

Esta línea de código cambia la propiedad del directorio /var/www y de todos sus contenidos (**incluido /storage/logs/laravel.log**) al usuario y el grupo del mismo especificado por el ARG $user.

Answer (score 0):

Muestro resolucion del problema con una linea de comando:  `chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: ya  realice una respuesta mejor